# Webpack watch script throws an error after couple successfull compiles.Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, webpack, homestead, laravel-mix

Bundle compiles successfully couple of times but then i get this error:

**Error:**

```
95% emittingError: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'D:\Web Development\Projects\GUIRebuild\public\js\super_admin_bundle.js
'
    at Error (native)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules
--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Smolen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-01T05_07_28_612Z-debug.log
```

**Log:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Smolen\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'watch' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v6.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: C:\Users\Smolen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\Web Development\Projects\GUIRebuild\node_modules\.bin;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;D:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Users\Smolen\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Smolen\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Users\Smolen\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: D:\Web Development\Projects\GUIRebuild
10 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Smolen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Smolen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd D:\Web Development\Projects\GUIRebuild
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Smolen\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v6.11.3
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have no idea why is this happening, i am using vagrant and virtual box but this compiles on my machine not on the virtual one.I get this "Unknown error" on random files.

What i have tried:

1. Remove/Reinstall node_modules
2. Upgrade Node and NPM
3. Clear NPM cache

**OS:** Windows 7 
**Laravel:** 5.4v 
**NPM:** 5.5.1v

Answer (score 2):

You can try removing node_modules folder and run again 
`npm install`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the output directory was corrupted and could not be opened anymore, so webpack could not access it.

Working around that by checking out the project in another location was the fastest solution, as deleting the directory was not easy and required repairing the drive with the windows repair tool (Right-Click in File Manager on Drive -> Properties -> Tools -> Disk Check).

Comment: Exactly my case. Thank you!